# What’s the meaning of “the final balance now due”?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

What’s the meaning “the final balance now due”
And what’s the meaning of “due” in this sentence ?
Please describe simple.
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it is off topic. [Example of a quick google search for the phrase](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/due)

Answer (score 2):

"due" in that phrase means "owing". This is saying  that the amount you now owe whatever business sent the letter is {Amount}.

> The Final Balance now due is XXX.

means the same as

> You now owe us XXX. Please pay us right away.